# How to get batch cmd output continuously in java application

Tags: java, multithreading, process, buffer, outputstream

I have wrote a program which run a batch command (tshark) to capture packet size between 2 ip address (continuously).

I used `Runtime` and `Process` to run it and `process.getOutputStream()` to get the returned values and print them in the java terminal.

My problem is that the print makes pauses between two records (print 1200 lines / stop 10 sec / print 1200 lines).

Do you know a way to read continuously, in the java app, the `OutputStream` of batch command ?

Comment: Can you add code?

Comment: did you mean `bash` command? and `tshark` ?

Comment: _**idan**_ : Code is in my answer.

_**Bentaye**_
It's a batch (Windows) command.
It's tshark you're right i correct my post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to read the `InputStream`: You read **from** an `InputStream`, you write **to** an `OutputStream`. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830698/what-is-inputstream-output-stream-why-and-when-do-we-use-them)

Then use a `BufferReader` to wrap your `OutputStream` and read it line by line in a while loop.

You can also catch the error `InputStream`. It might be useful to debug if you don't see any output.

Here is an example with the `ping` command. As I don't know what your `tsharp` command is.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("ping www.google.com");

String line = null;

BufferedReader inputStreamReader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
while ((line = inputStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

BufferedReader errorStreamReader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = errorStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly my code. Ping comand end quickly so if i wait few seconds i have the result. Tshark capture network trafic so doesn't end.

My problem is that the reading make pauses.

This is my code :

```
    String cmd = "c:\\\"Program Files\"\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe -T fields -e frame.len host"+ ipSrc +" and dst "+ ipDst;

    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", cmd};

    try {
        final Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also tried to use a Thread to write in terminal but it's the same problem :

```
    new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    process.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```